# Cassandra 3.0.9 service is active then exited

Tags: cassandra

I am using Cassandra 3.0.9,service is active then exited,

Can't remove package and install again because no repository on Cassandra is providing this version, can't go far tarball as it again leads to other issues systemd creation and others.  Pls share complete steps to make it work 3.0.9 Cassandra which was installed on my server Ubuntu from long time.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check the logs for clues on why the service isn't running. Without information on what problem you're facing, we are not able to provide anything meaningful.

As a side note, you also didn't provide details of how you were checking for the existence of Cassandra 3.0.9 so I'm not sure we can help you there. In any case, I've checked [the archive server](https://archive.apache.org/dist/cassandra/debian/pool/main/c/cassandra/) (linked in the official [Apache Cassandra Download](https://cassandra.apache.org/_/download.html) page) and can confirm that the 3.0.9 package exists.

A friendly note that you need to provide sufficient details when asking a question. The general guidance is that you (a) provide a good summary of the problem that includes software/component versions, the full error message + full stack trace; (b) describe what you've tried to fix the problem, details of investigation you've done; and (c) steps to replicate the problem.

For guidance, see [Asking Good Cassandra Questions](https://cassandra.apache.org/_/community/ask_good_questions.html) I published on the Apache Cassandra website. Additionally since you're new to DBA Stack Exchange, I would recommend taking [the tour](https://stackexchange.com/tour) and reading [the guide on how to ask questions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Cheers!